# Changing the Imageview source from another java class

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

In my application I am using the android fingerprint manager to verify the user, once the user has been verified, I would like the icon that is on the activity to another icon that is a different colour (same vector - different colour, different drawable file).
Below is the code for the activity containing the imageview:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Lock screen security not enabled in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings to continue",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    generateKey();
    if (cipherInit()) {
        cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
        FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
        helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);

    }
}

public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
            | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }
    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Here is the XML for the same activity:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splashgradient"
tools:context="com.example.maxrw.tferfilemanager.HomeActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewfinger"
    android:layout_width="309dp"
    android:layout_height="155dp"
    android:text="Please authorise using Nexus Inprint"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewFinger"
    android:layout_width="196dp"
    android:layout_height="167dp"
    app:srcCompat="?android:attr/fingerprintAuthDrawable"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewfinger"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
```

And finally this is the code for the java class that links to the previously mentioned activity (this class has no activity of its own):

```
public class FingerprintHandler extends
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

    private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
    private Context appContext;

    public FingerprintHandler(Context context) {
        appContext = context;
    }

    public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager,
                          FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {

        cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
                Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId,
                                      CharSequence errString) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication error\n" + errString,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId,
                                     CharSequence helpString) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication help\n" + helpString,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication failed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
            FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

        appContext.startActivity(new Intent(appContext, MainActivity.class));

        imageViewFinger.setImageResource(R.drawable.fingerprintgreen);



        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication succeeded.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

The code that has the problem is at the end of the second java class:

```
imageViewFinger.setImageResource(R.drawable.fingerprintgreen);
```

Cheers for any help you guys can provide :)

Comment: Please post your findViewById code. i cant find it..

Comment: ImageView imageViewFinger = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewFinger)
            Drawable new_image= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fingerprintgreen);
            imageViewFinger.setBackgroundDrawable(new_image);

Comment: I added that code after I posted in replacement of the other code that I specified at the end, this code still doesnt work

Comment: how do you pass the refrenece of the ImageView from activity to the FingerprintHandler class..

Comment: I dont know thats what I need to find out. I looked at source code from other people and tried to get it to work.

Comment: After you take the refenece from the xml you need to send the refrenece to the other class maybe send it in Constractor of the same class in order.. if you build the fingerprint class from the activity example    public FingerprintHandler(Context context,ImageView image) {
        appContext = context; imageViewFinger = image;
    }